# How to wait for the result of a database read in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, firebase-realtime-database

In my application I use Firebase Realtime Database to store data about users. I would like to be sure that when I read this data to display it in the view (e.g. their nickname), that the reading has been done before displaying it. Let me explain:

```
//Initialization of user properties
    static func initUsers(){
        let usersref = dbRef.child("Users").child(userId!)
        usersref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
            if let infos = DataSnapshot.value as? [String : Any]{
                self.username = infos["username"] as! Int
                 
                //The VC is notified that the data has been recovered
                let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "dataRetrieved")
                let notification = Notification(name: name)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that runs in the model and reads the user's data when they log in.

```
var isFirstAppearance = true
 
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         
        //We initialise the properties associated with the user
        Users.initUsers()
    }
     
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if isFirstAppearance {
            let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "dataRetrieved")
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(registerDataToView), name: name, object: nil)
            isFirstAppearance = false
        }
        else{
            registerDataToView()
        }
    }
 
    //The user's data is assigned to the view
    @objc func registerDataToView(){
        usernameLabel.text = String(Users.username)
    }
```

Here we are in the VC and when the view loads we call initUsers in viewDidLoad. In viewWillAppear, if it's the first time we load the view then we create a listener which calls registerDataToView if the reading in the database is finished. Otherwise we simply call registerDataToView (this is to update the labels when we return to this VC).

I would like to know if it is possible, for example when we have a very bad connection, that the listener does not intercept the dataRetrieved notification and therefore that my UI displays only the default texts? Or does the headset wait to receive the notification before moving on?

If it doesn't wait then how can I wait for the database read to finish before initializing the labels?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't wait. Never wait.** Tell the receiver that the data are available with a completion handler

```
static func initUsers(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let usersref = dbRef.child("Users").child(userId!)
    usersref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
        if let infos = DataSnapshot.value as? [String : Any]{
            self.username = infos["username"] as! Int
            completion(true)
            return
        }
        completion(false)
    }
    
}
```

And use it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
    //We initialise the properties associated with the user
    Users.initUsers { [unowned self] result in
        if result (
          // user is available 
        } else {
          // user is not available 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but if the user has a bad connection, how do I make him wait for the data to be read so I can display it in the view. Otherwise the UI will not be complete. I had thought of putting the associated labels in hidden if the reading takes time and when it finishes I display them with the associated data. Is this a good solution?